# Diferenças entre as versões do Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Olá ! Recentemente decidi iniciar os estudos da linguagem Python, no entanto, ao pesquisar sobre a linguagem, percebi que existem diferenças entre a versão 2 e 3. Essas diferenças realmente são significativas ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Essas diferenças realmente são significativas ?

Do ponto de vista da sintaxe, do aprendizado, etc, não, não são. Você pode perfeitamente aprender o "jeito do Python 2" e o "jeito do Python 3" simultaneamente, e até usar ora um ora outro dependendo da situação (falo de pequenos scripts somente, e logo você vai entender por que).

Mas do ponto de vista da manutenabilidade, sim, essas diferenças podem ser uma grande pedra no seu sapato, caso você inicie um projeto em uma versão e depois decida mudar pra outra. Por essa razão, se você está começando agora, e principalmente se pretende fazer algum sistema com ciclo de vida mais longo, eu recomendaria o seguinte:

1. Use as características do Python 3 sempre que possível: `print` como função, strings unicode sem `u` na frente, divisão inteira resultando em ponto flutuante, etc. Conheça as diferenças pro Python 2 para saber melhor reconhecer discrepâncias e corrigir os bugs, mas não se habitue a fazer algo que mudou do 2 pro 3, mesmo se estiver programando no 2;
2. Se você precisa fazer algo no 2 que só foi introduzido no 3, em geral não há problema: é para isso que o módulo `__future__` existe. As principais diferenças entre as versões (essas 3 que mencionei e mais uma 4ª que desconheço) foram *"backported"* pro Python 2.7, de modo que podem ser utilizadas desde que você inclua o seguinte no início do seu arquivo:

   ```
   from __future__ import absolute_import
   from __future__ import division
   from __future__ import print_function
   from __future__ import unicode_literals
   ```

   Além disso, como [esse guia de portabilidade](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) (em inglês) menciona, invocar o Python com a flag `-3` faz com que ele te avise de potenciais incompatibilidades entre as duas versões;
3. Se não tiver razão para programar no 2 (ex.: alguma biblioteca fundamental ao seu projeto que só existe pro 2), prefira o 3. Alguns sistemas operacionais vêm com o 2 instalado por padrão (o que significa mais trabalho para configurar corretamente o 3), mas procure não deixar isso te atrapalhar de usar a versão mais nova, se viável.

### Diferenças mais impactantes

Dito isso, não sei dizer quais são todas essas diferenças, mas dentre as principais [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html) as que considero mais impactantes são as seguintes:

- `print` no 3 é uma função, e não uma instrução:

  ```
  print 42  # Python 2
  print(42) # Python 3
  ```
- Várias funções *built-in* e métodos dos principais tipos, que antes retornavam listas, agora retornam iteradores. Isso não é um problema nos usos mais corriqueiros, mas se em algum momento você realmente precisar de uma lista, acostume-se a criar uma explicitamente:

  ```
  x = list(range(10)) # No Python 2 range já retorna uma lista, você apenas a copia
                      # No Python 3 range retorna um iterador, é preciso criar a lista

  for i in range(10): # Igual em ambos (mais eficiente no 3)
  ```
- Strings no 3 são Unicode por padrão, e sequências de bytes devem estar prefixadas por `b`:

  ```
  x = "Olá" # No 2, sem o "import unicode_literals", seria inválido

  x = u"Olá" # Como era no 2, NÃO RECOMENDADO usar em códigos novos

  y = b"\x80" # Só existe a partir do 3; note que 0x80 não é um caractere ASCII válido
  ```
- Inteiro dividido por inteiro é inteiro no 2, mas é ponto flutuante no 3:

  ```
  x = 3/2  # 1.5 no Python 3, 1 no Python 2 sem o "import division"

  y = 3//2 # 1 em ambos ("//" é a divisão inteira)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Nem tanto. Se não há requisitos para usar a versão 2.7, porque vai trabalhar com algum sistema legado, é bastante óbvio que deve aprender em cima da versão mais nova, no caso a 3.5.1, ela é bem superior. Se um dia precisar usar uma versão mais antiga por qualquer razão, será fácil se adaptar.

Existe uma [página oficial sobre o assunto](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3).